# Select a través de Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, select

Me gustaría rellenar este `select` a través de `Jquery` y no `HTML`

```
  <select id="multipleICOs" class="form-control" required>
        <!--It is NEEDED to check first if there are more than an ICO-->
    <option type="text" *ngFor="let ico of icos">{{ico.icoDisplayName}}</option>
  </select>
```

Básicamente necesito el mismo código pero a través de `Jquery`

Comment: Algo asi como con un bucle?

Answer (score 1):

Saludos Buenos Dias @mario . Para realizar un "populate" con php desde JSON con jquery, puedes usar este codigo.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON("../controller/archivophp.php",{action:"llenar_select"}, function(select_json_data)
    {
        var variable_data = "";
        $.each(select_json_data, function(key,value)
        {
            variable_data += "<option value='"+value.id+"'>" +value.nombre+ "</option>";
        })
        $(".select").append(variable_data);
    })  
})
```